# a small questions on web part, sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a empty web part, then created a usercontrol, in UserControl.ascx.cs, I wrote like that:

```
namespace tasks_email.ControlTemplates.tasks_email
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

        public tasks_email WebPart { get; set; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

then it said:"tasks_email.Controltemplates.tasks_email" is a 'namesspace' but is used like a 'type'

Can any body tell me where the problem is and give me some suggestion?

Comment: What is the actual type supposed to be?  I think the error message is rather clear.  You have entered a namespace, but it expects a Type.  The type of a variable cannot be an entire namespace.  Oh, and if you want to create a webpart with a user control inside of it you can just use the "Visual web part" template in visual studio.  It will create a webpart, and a user control, and add the user control to the webpart all for you, and even package the whole thing into one collapsible component in solution explorer.  It's quite convenient.

Comment: cool! that worked! btw, can you tell me what the namespace truly mean? (I'm a C# starter)

Comment: A namespace is simply a way of grouping related classes together.  In The "full name" of any class includes both it's actual type name as well as the full namespace, i.e. `String` is actually `System.String`.  It doesn't really *do* much of anything; it just helps keep your classes organized.

Comment: I ran the server, it showed me <nativehr>0X80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestatck>Access denied

Comment: The important bit of that error message is the `Access denied` part.  Clearly you don't have access to that site, or your code is doing something that you don't have access to do.

Comment: do you familiar with this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a webpart with a user control inside of it you can just use the "Visual web part" template in visual studio. It will create a webpart, and a user control, and add the user control to the webpart all for you, and even package the whole thing into one collapsible component in solution explorer. It's quite convenient.  Doing all of that work yourself (for every new webpart) is just a pain.

Comment: I ran the server, it showed me <nativehr>0X80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestatck>Access denied, do you have any ideas about this question?

Comment: Yes, as I have already told you, it means you don't have access to do something that your code is doing.  In any case, it's a separate question that's unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace tasks_email.ControlTemplates.tasks_email
```

Here you declare tasks_email as a namespace.

```
public tasks_email WebPart { get; set; }
```

Here you declare a member called WebPart, with a type tasks_email.  That's not a type - you've already said it's a namespace.  I can't guess what you really meant.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try "namespace tasks_email.ControlTemplates"? Because the way you do it, you use tasks_email like a type indeed ; and not as a namespace

Comment: I ran the server, it showed me <nativehr>0X80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestatck>Access denied, do you have any ideas about this question?